# Converting IronPython file object to .NET Stream object

Tags: ironpython

Is there an easy way to convert an IronPython file-like object to a .NET Stream? The reverse can be done in IronPython using code like this:

```py
net_stream = File.OpenRead('file.txt')
python_file = file(net_stream)
```

Is there an easy way to convert it back? Or do you have to write a wrapper that will inherit from `Stream` and implement all the methods?

Comment: FWIW, I wanted to do the opposite, so your question code was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently it's possible to do it like this:

```
import System
f = file('abc.txt', 'w+')
f.GetType().GetField('_stream', System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(f)
```

Comment: But this only works if it's a "real" file object building on a .NET stream, not for arbitrary file-like objects (duck typing).